# Keyboard layout bug in login window after screen lock

Tags: keyboard-layout

I use Fedora 16 now, but this issue already was in Fedora 15 before I upgraded it.

When I lock my screen and then want to unlock it, I have a default English layout (I am from Russia and also have Russian layout). My layout switching shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

When I try to enter my password, I get a login failure, and I must switch layouts twice (to Russian and again to English), and then login is successful. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What is your GUI & Login Manager?  And how have you installed the Russian layout?

Comment: I use default Gnome 3. I've installed Russian layout while Fedora installing :)